# Overriding global operator new to track huge memory allocations?

Tags: c++

I am trying to produce a special build of a large monolithic application. The problem I am trying to solve is tracking hard-to-reproduce huge memory allocations (30-80 gigabytes, judging by what OS reports).
I believe the problem is an std::vector resized to a negative 32-bit integer value. The only platform exhibiting this behavior is Solaris (maybe it's the only platform that manages to successfully allocate such chunks of contiguous memory).
Can I globally replace std::vector with my class, delegating all calls to the real vector, watching for suspicious allocations `(size > 0x7FFFFFFFu)`? Maybe selectively replace the constructor that takes `size_t` and the `resize()` methods? Maybe even hijacking the global operator new?

Comment: a 32 bit value cannot IMO result in 30-80 GigaByte ,do you mean 64 bit

Comment: An array of 0xFFFFFFFF 8-byte structures takes ~34 gigabytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not to do something like this?

```
void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    // if (size > MAX_SIZE) ...
    return malloc(size);
}

void *operator new [](size_t size)
{
    // if (size > MAX_SIZE) ...
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Setting a breakpoint in the `if` would find the problem right away.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. Of course, `operator new` is already defined in the platform's standard library, so I cannot simply provide a second implementation.

Comment: It would be great if I could simply do it like that. I'll try.

Comment: don't forget to add corresponding operator delete.

Comment: It worked. I had to override four versions of new (throw and no-throw `new` and array `new`) and four versions of delete. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a custom allocator on your vector at the time it's constructed.

You could just delegate to `std::allocator`, and firewall the requested memory size, in the first instance.

Comment: You see, the problem is I have no idea which part of the code misbehaves. Modifying the whole codebase (including third-party libraries?) with custom allocators everywhere a vector is used is hardly possible.

Comment: Yes, that's harder then.  The q read like you might already know which vector this is.  Does your platform offer any means to attribute heap blocks by creating callstack?

Comment: I can log the call stack when I detect a suspicious condition. The question is how to detect it globally, without changing every single class using a vector.

Comment: @Alex - I was referring to possible use of some external tool for memory misuse - c.f. valgrind on Linux?  Sorry, I am a Windows guy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementation of the `std::vector` class on the problem platform.  Each implementation handles memory management differently (e.g. some double the currently allocated space when you add an object outside the vector's currently allocation size).  If your objects are sufficiently large and/or you have a large number of entries being added to the vector, would be possible to attempt to allocate beyond the available (contiguous) memory on the computer.  If that is the case, you'll want to look into a custom allocator for that vector.

If you're storing that many large items in a vector, you may want to look into another collection (e.g. `std::list`) or try storing pointers instead of actual objects.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is not how to modify the code to use less memory. I am trying to find the buggy piece of code that effectively does `vector.resize((size_t)(-1))`. Once that piece is identified, it should be a trivial task to fix it.

Comment: If you have access to a debugger that has conditional breakpoint capability, that would do the trick.  Otherwise, try cutting your collection in half and test to see if you run into the same problem.  Increase your collection by half of the remaining items until you see the problem.  My gut reaction would be that somewhere along the way the stock allocator is being tasked with increasing your collection's capacity by double its current capacity and is running out of contiguous memory to allocate.

Comment: the code will be run on customer's site in their QA environment. I can access the results of that run (log files), but I cannot demand they run it in a debugger.

Comment: In that case, add some debug output to your log files.  Anytime an item is inserted or removed from the vector, print it, along with the current size and capacity of the vector.  That should tell you where you run into the problem.

Comment: exactly. The question is how to insert my code into something `std::vector`'s implementation is doing without changing thousands of source files.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own `allocator` type to `std::vector` to track allocation.
But I doubt that's the reason. First, looking at the sizes (30-80GB) I conclude it's a 64-bit code. How could 32-bit negative integer value make it to vector size, which is 64-bit, it would have been promoted to 64-bit first to preserve value? Second, if this problem only occurs on Solaris then it can indicate a different problem. As far as I remember, Solaris is the only OS that commits memory on allocation, the other operating systems only mark the address space allocated until those memory pages are actually used. So I would search for unused allocations.

Comment: How could a negative 32-bit value make it to a vector size? Something like this: `uint32_t count = (uint32_t)GetNumberOfThings(); std::vector things(Thing(), count);` when `GetNumberOfThings` returns -1 on error. And yes, the existing code base uses a lot of 32-bit sized variables and even has a custom vector implementation using 32-bit size. The problem is tracking down the offending piece of code...